# Haskell Type matching error when passing two Lists

Tags: list, haskell, type-mismatch

I'm getting started learning Haskell and have to create a really simple function that takes two Lists and concats them.

```
app :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]  
app xs ys = xs ++ ys
```

This is part of a task where we have to benchmark smaller functions like these.
I do this with Criterion. The complete code is as following:

```
import Criterion.Main
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "normal 100" [ bench "app"     $ whnf app $ [0..49] [50..100]
                      ]
                  ]
app :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]  
app xs ys = xs ++ ys
```

The compiling fails and leaves me with this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Integer] -> [a0]'
           with actual type `[Integer]'
The function `[0 .. 49]' is applied to one argument,
but its type `[Integer]' has none
In the second argument of `($)', namely `[0 .. 49] [50 .. 100]'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `whnf app $ [0 .. 49] [50 .. 100]'
```

I have a real problem in decrypting ghc error messages and am basically stuck here.  
I know there are a lot of questions regarding type-mismatches here but i couldn't find a solution.  
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend rewriting this without using `$` anywhere, only using parentheses, then adding `$` back in after you get it working if you really want to.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yeah i tried that already but i got the same error so i left them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signatures of `bench` and `whnf` are:

```
bench :: String        -> Benchmarkable -> Benchmark
whnf  :: (a -> b) -> a -> Benchmarkable
```

Since `app` takes two arguments, we need to curry the first one in the call to `whnf`:

```
whnf (app [0..49]) [50..100]  :: Benchmarkable
```

Note that `whnf` has two arguments: `(app [0..49])` and `[50..100]`.

Now we can form the call to `bench`:

```
bench "app" ( whnf (app [0..49]) [50..100] )  :: Benchmark
```

If we want to use $, there is only one place where we can use it:

```
bench "app" $ whnf (app [0..49]) [50..100]
```

We can't place a $ after `whnf` because in general:

```
a b c   ==  (a b) c
```

and

```
a $ b c == a (b c)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!